# Rails with postgres, recreating a table after it was dropped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I ran this command to drop one of my tables and it worked fine.

> DROP TABLE gallery_images;

Now I want to recreate that table, and running a rake:db migrate isn't doing anything. What needs to be done to recreate it? Here's what the migration file looks like.

```
class CreateGalleryImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :gallery_images do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.string :source
      t.string :thumb
      t.string :large
      t.string :original
      t.string :link

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the row in the `schema_migrations` table with the same timestamp as the timestamp in the migration's filename. Then run `rake db:migrate` again.

Comment: In the future, s/he should use `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<migration version>` in order to drop a table. This way, `schema_migrations` are updated accordingly.